# Display managers don't log me into my user account

Tags: linux, arch-linux, login, display-manager, login-manager

I have been using Arch Linux for more than 5 years now (and linux for about 10 years).  Never had such a problem. Searching the internet also did not reveal any answers to this ----

Here are the core points of the issue:
**1**. Display managers (gdm, lightdm) don't let me log into my usual user account named "mumtaz". They just waste a minute or two and either come back to the login screen (gdm) or hang altogether (lightdm).
**2**. Display managers easily log into root and newly created accounts. DMs don't have any problem with any newly created accounts. I created and tested a new account named "test". It worked perfectly. Also root works fine.  This problem is only with a single account "mumtaz" and only with display managers.
**3**. Loging  into my "mumtaz" account  through TTYs goes through without problem. And I can do anything as "mumtaz" on the TTYs.
**4**. Earlier -- I tried changing the password of "mumtaz" through my root account --- it changed the password --- but the problem, as described in above three points persisted.
**5**. So in summary of above:
---  TTYs allow me to login in any account (including "mumtaz") -- and do anything I want. There is no issue on TTYs.
---  All DMs work fine with other accounts.  Not with "mumtaz".
---- All desktop environments on my machine (gnome, plasma) work fine when used with any DM and with any other account (except "mumtaz").
-- --  I just can't get into the DEs via DMs as "mumtaz".
**6**. The home directory of "mumtaz" can be accessed from other accounts.
**7**. I haven't tried startx / xinit way of starting the graphical environment from TTYs  as I did not think its relevant.
**8**. uname -a
Linux TECRA 5.2.0-arch2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 8 18:18:54 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You have some broken `~/.xsession`, `~/.xprofile` or similar script. Have a look inside `~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: Notice that the new switch to wayland/systemd/etc may break a lot of things that were working perfectly fine before. It's not clear from your answer if logging stopped after an upgrade or just out of the blue.

Comment: I second mosvy's first assertion ... there's a high likelihood that some file crucial to X is either owned by someone else and/or that you don't have write permissions to it.  Try a `find -xdev $HOME \( \! -user mumtaz -o \! -perm -u+w  \)  -printf "%u\t%m\t%f\n"`

Comment: Did you find a solution? This happened to me yesterday after an update to my system. Haven't found any answers yet

Comment: Don't remember what I did to solve it.  
But in 2020 I changed my distribution to Ubuntu and have not faced any such problems since then.